# Effect dispatched an invalid action:

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I use Angular 7.1.4

My Effect:

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoginEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private authService: AuthenticationService) {
  }

  @Effect({dispatch: true})
  loginRequest$: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(LoginActionsType.LOGIN_REQUEST),
    exhaustMap(payload => { // it might be switchMap, the error is the same.
      console.log(payload);
      return this.authService.login(payload.user, payload.password) // TypeScript Errors: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'never'. ; TS2339: Property 'password' does not exist on type 'never'.
        .pipe(
          map(user => new LoginSuccessAction(user)),
          catchError( err => of(new LogOutAction(err)))
        );
    })
  );
}
```

And i get this error: ERROR Error: Effect "LoginEffects.loginRequest$" dispatched an invalid action: ...

[image]

If i add {dispatch: false} in the @Effect decorator, the error is gone.

Also i get typescript errors if try to access payload properties.

Answer (score 2):

All actions must have a `type` property to identify them. Looking at the error log your action only contains a payload. Make sure that `LoginSuccessAction` and `LogOutAction` both have a readonly `type` property. Example:

```js
class LoginSuccessAction extends Action {
  readonly type = "LOGIN_SUCCESS";
}
```

Comment: You are right. There was a typo in LoginSuccessAction