# My effect dispatched an invalid action or infinite loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, roles, ngrx-effects

I'm new with ngrx and I hope someone can be kind and help me because i read a lot of topics about this problem, and i am still in the same point.
I am testing `@ngrx/effects` and i just want to return a simple array of roles users at the start of application (just for understand how its work for the moment).
When i use this code below:

```
 ...
 ...
 switchMap(() => this.roleService.getAllRoles().pipe(
   map(roles => {
     return new AllRolesLoaded({ roles });
   }),
   catchError((error) => of(new ErrorLoadRole(error)))
 )),
// I got infinite loop
```

I got an infinite loop.
With my research on stackflow i found i have to use `.tap()` instead of `.map()`.
But when i use `.tap()`:

```
 ...
 ...
 switchMap(() => this.roleService.getAllRoles().pipe(
   tap(roles => {
     return new AllRolesLoaded({ roles });
   }),
   catchError((error) => of(new ErrorLoadRole(error)))
 )),

// I got this:
// core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Effect "RoleEffects.loadRoles$" dispatched an invalid action:   ...
// core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Actions must have a type property
```

For invalid action, i tried:
- [Effect dispatched an invalid action:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481888/effect-dispatched-an-invalid-action)
- the version with decorator `@Effect` (ngrx 8.0.1), the version `createEffect()` (ngrx 8.3.0).
- `swithMap()` `mergeMap()` `exhaustMap()` ect... and i have the sama result.

Here full code, maybe you can understand what's happen here.

```
//  #actions/role.actions.ts

// ngrx version 8.0.1
export enum RoleActionTypes {
  RequestLoadRoles = '[Role] Request Load data Roles',
  AllRolesLoaded = '[Roles API] All Roles Loaded',
  ErrorLoadRole = '[Roles API] Error load roles',
}

export class RequestLoadRoles implements Action {
  readonly type = RoleActionTypes.RequestLoadRoles;
}
export class AllRolesLoaded implements Action {
  readonly type = RoleActionTypes.AllRolesLoaded;
  constructor(public payload: { roles: Role[] }) {}
}
export class ErrorLoadRole {
  readonly type = RoleActionTypes.ErrorLoadRole;
  constructor(public payload: HttpErrorResponse) {}
}

// ngrx version 8.3.0 but i cannot handle it yet
// export const RequestLoadRoles = createAction('[Role] Request Load data Roles');
// export const AllRolesLoaded = createAction('[Roles API] All Roles Loaded', props<{ role: Role[] }>());

 export type RoleActions =
   | RequestLoadRoles
   | AllRolesLoaded
   | ErrorLoadRole
   ;

//  #effects/role.effect.ts

@Injectable()
export class RoleEffects {

// ngrx version 8.0.1
@Effect()
loadRoles$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<RequestLoadRoles>(RoleActionTypes.RequestLoadRoles),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(roles => roles.rolesLoaded))),
  filter(([action, loaded]) => !loaded),
  switchMap(() => this.roleService.getAllRoles().pipe(
    tap(roles => { // with .tap() i got the invalid dispatched action, i dont know why, and .map() give my an infinite loop
      return new AllRolesLoaded({ roles });
    }),
    catchError((error) => of(new ErrorLoadRole(error)))
  )),
);

// ngrx version 8.3.0 but i cannot handle it yet
// loadRoles$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
//   ofType('[Roles API] All Roles Loaded'),
//   mergeMap(() => this.roleService.getAllRoles()
//     .pipe(
//       map(roles => ({ type: '[Roles API] All Roles Loaded', payload: roles })),
//       catchError(() => EMPTY)
//     ))
//   )
// );

@Effect()
init$: Observable<RoleActions> = defer(() => {
  return of(new RequestLoadRoles());
});
constructor(private actions$: Actions, private store: Store<RolesStateEntity>, private roleService: RoleService) {}
```

}

```
# reducer/role.reducer.ts
export const roleFeatureKey = 'role';

export interface RolesStateEntity {
  rolesLoaded: boolean;
  rolesLoading: boolean;
  queryResult: Role[];
}

export const initialRolesState: RolesStateEntity = {
  rolesLoaded: false,
  rolesLoading: false,
  queryResult: []
};


export function roleReducer(state = initialRolesState, action: RoleActions): RolesStateEntity {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RoleActionTypes.AllRolesLoaded:
      return {
        ...state,
        queryResult: action.payload.roles,
        rolesLoading: false,
        rolesLoaded: true,
     };
    case RoleActionTypes.ErrorLoadRole:
     return {
        ...state,
        rolesLoading: false,
     };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

  # service/role.service.ts there is only 1 method
  getAllRoles(): Observable<Role[]> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      const array = [
        {
          name: 'ADMIN',
          permissions: ['fullAccessUserManagement', 'canDeleteUserManagement', 'canUpdateUserManagement', 'canReadUserManagement'],
        },
        {
          name: 'MODERATOR',
          permissions: ['canDeleteUserManagement', 'canUpdateUserManagement', 'canReadUserManagement'],
        },
        {
          name: 'USER',
          permissions: ['canReadUserManagement'],
        },
        {
          name: 'GUEST',
          permissions: [],
        },
      ]
     observer.next(array);
    });
  }
```

Here the full error of console:

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Effect "RoleEffects.loadRoles$" dispatched an invalid action: [{"name":"ADMIN","permissions":["fullAccessUserManagement","canDeleteUserManagement","canUpdateUserManagement","canReadUserManagement"]},{"name":"MODERATOR","permissions":["canDeleteUserManagement","canUpdateUserManagement","canReadUserManagement"]},{"name":"USER","permissions":["canReadUserManagement"]},{"name":"GUEST","permissions":[]}]
at reportInvalidActions (effects.js:338)
at MapSubscriber.project (effects.js:428)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:29)
at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at ExhaustMapSubscriber.notifyNext (exhaustMap.js:60)
at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:69)
at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
...
Show 139 more frames
core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Actions must have a type property
at ActionsSubject.next (store.js:168)
at Store.next (store.js:709)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:69)
at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at Notification.observe (Notification.js:20)
```

I say again here, i got the data, but i got this error too (when i use `.tap()`).
The other error is the infinite loop (with `.map()`).

I thank you by advance if you took the time to read that, and i will appreciate your help me because at this moment I'm in black hole.

[My photo of infinite loop here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJCes.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved my problem. I put the explanation below.

From `app.module.ts` i had this:

```
imports: [
   ...
   EffectsModule.forRoot([]), 
   StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { // this is made by cmd : ng g store AppState --root --module app.module.ts
     metaReducers,
     runtimeChecks: {
       strictStateImmutability: true,
       strictActionImmutability: true,
     },
   }),
]
```

And i had this on my `front.module.ts`: 
NB: I decided to made 2 modules (1 front, 1 back)

```
imports: [
   ...
   StoreModule.forFeature(roleFeatureKey, rolesReducer),
   EffectsModule.forFeature([PermissionEffects, RolesEffects]),
]
```

I found a lot of examples for init data with nrgx here: 
 - https://dev.to/jonrimmer/where-to-initiate-data-load-in-ngrx-358l 
 and i did the same thing.

So my new `app.module.ts` is like this now:

```
import { rolesReducer } from './reducer/role';
...
... 
imports: [
   ...
   EffectsModule.forRoot([RolesEffects]),
   StoreModule.forRoot({ roles: rolesReducer }),
   StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
     maxAge: 25,
   }),
]
```

And in `front.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
   ...
   i deleted,
   i deleted,
]
```

I still dont know why it didnt work before, i was thinking it could work, maybe this is my error. 
The doc said :

> For feature modules, register your effects by adding the EffectsModule.forFeature() method in the imports array of your NgModule.

Maybe we cannot do that when we init data 
Like this it work perfectly. I hope i won't have more problems ^^.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `map` instead of `tap`.
`tap` does not return a value, so it means you will dispatch the service's result back to the store which is causing the invalid action error. With `map` you transform the service response to a valid NgRx Action.

The code you're showing, is valid so my guess would be that something else is causing the infinite loop.

```
 switchMap(() => this.roleService.getAllRoles().pipe(
   map(roles => {
     return new AllRolesLoaded({ roles });
   }),
   catchError((error) => of(new ErrorLoadRole(error)))
 )),
```

Comment: Hi tim, thank you for your answer. What is the possibilities to find the infinite loop issue? It can come from my `this.roleService.getAllRoles()`? or from my reducer? i tried `{dispatch: false}` but it doesnt work.

Comment: how do you dispatch the RequestLoadRoles  action?

Comment: In fact, i dont dispatch `RequestLoadRoles`. I called that action from init$, and his goal is too `loadRoles$` and dispatch this action `new AllRolesLoaded({ roles });`. I saw that example inside a template design, that why i thought i could do the same.

Comment: If you got a reproduction I'm can take a look

Comment: can you tell me how i can reproduce pls?

Comment: I don't know... that's up to you

Answer (score 0):

I believe this effect is the culprit:

```
@Effect()
init$: Observable<RoleActions> = defer(() => {
  return of(new RequestLoadRoles());
});
```

remove it and in the constructor of the service do

```
this.store.dispatch(new RequestLoadRoles());
```

PS .map() is used to transform the data of the pipeline (that's what you need: transform list of roles into a AllRolesLoaded action), and .tap() acts like a side effect, so the pipeline is not actually influenced

Comment: Thank you, i understand now the difference between `.map()` and `.tap()`. I tried to dispatch from my roleService constructor, but nothing happen. I added a lot of `console.log` everywhere, and i see nothing. I suppose the `RequestLoadRoles` didnt started.

Comment: it's gotta work, I don't see why it wouldn't. as for the infinite loop, is your AllRolesLoaded refucer influencing on what you get from this.roleService.getAllRoles() ?

Comment: I have just updated my post, and add my only one method in service and the reducer atleast you can see better.

Comment: could you also post the error log about the infinite loop?

Comment: there is no error, it just trigger my role object with no limit. I put a photo of my console if you want. I used a console.log(payload.role) in the action to see.

Comment: to tell the truth I'm at a loss. you can check where the problem is by putting .first() operator in different places of your effect to identify what exactly is causing the problem (after ofType(), after switchMap())

Comment: Me too, im  lost. I used `.first()` operator just after `ofType()` and i already see the infinite loop. Its request everytime the action`[Role] Request Load data Roles`